# Extending calendar functionality to accept years

Tags: php, date, calendar

I'm working on an event scheduler site and I am currently stuck as I'm using a Months table (with `id` & `month` as the headers) to group my results by month. Due to this, if I try to schedule an event for January 2016, it successfully puts it into the month I choose as intended, but understandably puts it into 2015.
I'm looking to get some help on extending this beyond the end of the current year and adding functionality for different years.

I would happily use another method than using my current table setup, so any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

Current code is as follows:

```
<?php include 'includes/connect.php';
include 'includes/header.php';
$curMonth = date("n"); ?>

<b>Upcoming Trip Information:</b><br><br>
<?php 
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM months ORDER BY id");
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
if($rows['id'] >= $curMonth ){

$monthname = $rows['month']; ?>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" width="100%"> 
<tr> 
<td>
<?php 
$tid = $_GET['transporter'];
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trips WHERE monthname(start_date) = '" . $rows['month'] . "' AND tid = '$tid'");
$check = mysql_num_rows($check);
if ($check < 1) {
echo "";
} else { ?> <h2><?php echo $monthname; ?><?php } ?></h2></td></tr> <tr> <?php $cmonth = date('F');
$tid = $_GET['transporter'];
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trips WHERE monthname(start_date) = '$monthname' ORDER BY start_date");
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res1)) {
$trid = $rows['trid'];
$trip_start = $rows['trip_start'];
$trip_end = $rows['trip_end'];
$start_date = $rows['start_date'];
$end_date = $rows['end_date'];
$colour = $rows['colour'];
$stime = strtotime($start_date);
$startt = date("l jS", $stime);
$etime = strtotime($end_date);
$endt = date("l jS", $etime); ?> 
<td valign="middle" style="height: 100px; background-color: #4b99ed; text-align: center;"> 
<div style="font-size: 17px; color: #ffffff;"><?php echo $trip_start; ?> to <?php echo $trip_end; ?></div> 
<div style="font-size: 15px; color: #ffffff;"><?php echo $startt; ?> - <?php echo $endt; ?></div> 

</td> 
<?php } } } ?> 
</tr> 
</table> <?php include 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

If possible I would like to maintain the results layout..

[image]

Comment: you would query `"SELECT * FROM months WHERE id >=$curMonth ORDER BY id"` to reduce the result set, but actually i would use a static array here `$months = array('','January','February',..etc..` and then you can do `foreach($months as $id=>$month) {...`

Comment: also check http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.add.php then you could just take `now()` and add 1 month in a loop, using that date object then for display since it will automatically go from dec 15 to jan 16 on +1 month

Comment: thanks for your responses, will definitely look up what you sent me, I'm still getting used to php coding so it's not quite second nature yet :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try, instead of using a `months` table, using the `start_date` column of your `trips` table.

Try changing your query:

```
SELECT trips.*, DATE_FORMAT('%M, %Y', start_date) as `dt` 
FROM trips  
WHERE tid = '$tid' /* This is bad, please prepare or escape your variables*/ 
ORDER BY `dt` ASC
```

You then won't have to do the first query to get all the months and loop through them. If you must have empty containers for each month, try using that query, but loop through a PHP-generated array of months to display.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried your suggestion but now it's only displaying the 1st result in the trips table and no other results.

Comment: Remove any GROUP BY from the query.

Comment: Thank you that has solved the 1 result issue, I'll look deeper into it because now the results are separated by the months as they previously were in my original code. I updated my original post with an image to show how I am trying to display the results, but not being limited by year obviously :)